# Compile IBase driver for Android using QT5

Tags: android, qt, firebird

I've been trying to compile the IBase driver for Android for a few days.
I already have a desktop application for Windows in which I have compiled the IBase driver to connect to the Firebird database. Everything works fine.

Now, I'm compiling the same desktop application for Android. The application compiles correctly and opens correctly on the Android phone.
But I need the Android application to also have a connection to a remote Firebird database. And this is the problem. I can't in any way generate the Ibase driver for Android.

My Android app always says:

> QSqlDatabase: QIBASE driver not loaded

I've already downloaded numerous files from Firebird to try to generate the .so file.

I use Firebird 2.5.8. I use Windows 10. I use Qt 5.14.2.

Any idea how to generate ibase driver for Android?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Isn't this something you should ask Qt support?